# upper bound for alternating sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, summation, analytic-number-theory, estimation

Let $f(n)$ be an arithmetic function such that $\frac{\log n}{\log 2}\leq f(n)\leq 2n$, for all positive integer $n$. By using other properties of $f(n)$ I can obtain 
$$
\sum_{n\leq x}f(n) = O\left(\dfrac{x^2}{(\log x)^{1/3}}\right).
$$
Now, I would like to find some upper bound for $|\sum_{n\leq x}(-1)^{n+1}f(n)|$.

In fact, my prediction is that $|\sum_{n\leq x}(-1)^{n+1}f(n)|=O(x^{3/2})$. However, I don't know too much tools to attack this kind of problem. Any one can give me some hint?

P.S. $f(n)$ is the smallest positive integer $k$ such that $n$ divides the $k$th Fibonacci number $F_k$.

Comment: You can't get any better bound just from what you've written. You could have $f(n)\sim\frac{\log n}{\log2}$ for odd $n$ and $f(n)\sim\frac n{(\log x)^{1/3}}$ for even $n$, and then the alternating sum would also be $O\left(\frac{x^2}{(\log x)^{1/3}}\right)$.

Comment: @joriki By these bounds yes, but as I said the function is $f(n)=\min\{k\geq 1: n\mid F_k\}$ and so $f(n)\gg \log n$ is too naive (in average). What I would like to know was some method to treat of these kind of sums (apart from splitting odd and even parts).

Comment: I think in that case I think you should rewrite the question a bit. It sounds a lot like you're introducing certain assumptions ("Let ...") and trying to deduce bounds from them. The $F_k$ part only appears in passing in the last sentence, labeled as a postscript.

Comment: @joriki Thanks! I only would like to know about some method to treat of asymptotics for alternating sums.